# Amazon SES - verificação de domínio em DNS Server da Registro.br

Tags: amazon-aws, dns, ses

Estou utilizando o serviço de DNS do registro.br, fiz uma verificação de domínio através do SES que pediu para que eu inserisse o seguinte código na linha TXT:

```
/xYz24aNPG4mH2k+amyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w=
```

Porém, ao tentar inseri-lo no DNS do registro.br acontece o seguinte "replace":

```
/xYz24aNPG4mH2kamyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w=
```

E a Amazon não consegue verificar o meu domínio, como posso resolver esta questão?

OBS: o sinal de **`+`** (plus, mais) é o que some do TXT

OBS2: este não é o número real gerado pela amazon SES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o registro.br não permite símbolos como o `+`, nem aspas, nem vários outros caracteres, apenas Letras, Dígitos e Hifem (LDH). Abaixo um email que enviei em 09/06/2014 para lá e o retorno:

EU:

> Bom dia,
>
> estou tentando criar um registro TXT para inserir informações de DKIM,
>   porém o editor do registro.br não permite digitar sobrescrito ("_") e
>   nem ponto-e-vírgula (";"). Como posso inserir o seguinte registro?
>
> domínio: imobiliariaxxx.com.br chave: mandrill._domainkey tipo: TXT
>   valor: v=DKIM1; k=rsa;
>   p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrLHiExVd55zd/IQ/J/mRwSRMAocV/hMB3jXwaHH36d9NaVynQFYV8NaWi69c1djDSAQzGt7yAioXqLj7Z4D2SSAoOLgrKsn8YnckGs9i3B3tVFB+Ch/4mPhXWiNfNdynHWBcPcbJ8kjEQ2U8y78dHZj1YeRXXVvWob2OaKynO8/lQIDAQAB;
>
> Att,
>
> Daniel Loureiro

Resposta em 09/06/2014 (pelo menos eles respondem bem rápido):

> Prezado Sr.,
>
> Nossos  servidores disponibilizam  um  serviço básico  e  por hora  só
>   suporta "labels" DNS  básicos (LDH - letras, digitos e  o hífen) mesmo
>   na interface de configuração "Avançada".
>
> A solução para este  caso, de uso mais avançado do  DNS, é a delegação
>   do domínio para outros servidores DNS aonde se tenha controle total da
>   "zona".
>
> Atenciosamente,
>
> Cristina ----

como eles mesmo disseram, para estes casos tem que usar outro DNS provider, como o Route53 ou até mesmo criar uma conta básica no serviço de hospedagem mais barato que achares, como a Kinghost (não é para usar a hospedagem em si, somente para o gerenciamento de DNS, mas já fica como bônus a hospedagem). A CloudFare faz este serviço de graça e é relativamente bem conhecida, mas não sei quais os contras de utilizar ela (pode ser que passe uma ideia de site amador caso seu site caia e apareça ela no lugar, ou que no futuro eles coloquem um banner no seu site, ou que os acessos sejam encaminhados à algum servidor deles, prejudicando a latência, etc - não sei).

Mas recomendo fortemente que mande um email para o registro.br, para que eles vejam que isto é uma demanda real e assim passem a ter este recurso de colocar caracteres "especiais" (caracteres além do LDH).

Espero que no futuro este meu post possa ser removido ou atualizado com a notícia de que o Registro.br suporta caracteres extra-LDH, mas até lá só nos resta reclamar com eles e usar outro serviço.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre insira registros TXT entre aspas duplas.

Adicione do seguinte modo:

`"/xYz24aNPG4mH2k+amyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w="`

e confira o resultado usando `dig`:

```
dig seudominio.com.br TXT
```

Se você está usando `aws`, recomendo que use o `route53`.

Comment: Não funcionou com aspas, talvez a melhor solução seja utilizar o route53, conforme sugerido.